# Why would java save empty strings when parsing this XML?

Tags: java, linux, string-parsing

I am trying to have java parse the lines of an XML file and when it finds the line contains a specific word, get the value out of that element. This is all done through string manipulation. I have tested locally that this works using a copy of the same file it would be looking at on the server it will end up.

However, for some reason when run through the remote server it does not work as intended. It shows only empty strings as a result where before it showed the text in the elements. The server where this is run is also actively reading from this file, but it should just be once at runtime for a different process. It is also still printing out the correct number of lines to show that it is seeing the correct values as it did before, and can correctly print those lines out to a log file if it does so in full.

This is the function that handles the parsing of the file:

```
private HashSet<String> parseFile() throws ProcessingException{
    String fileLocation = getInterfaceLocation();
    HashSet<String> fileMasks = new HashSet<String>();

    try {
        File file = new File(fileLocation);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        boolean inFileSet = false;

        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.toLowerCase().contains("<fileset")) {
                inFileSet = true;
                continue;
            }
            if(line.toLowerCase().contains("</fileset>")) {
                inFileSet = false;
            }

            if(inFileSet) {
                log(line);
                if(!line.toLowerCase().contains("<include")) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    line = line.substring(line.indexOf("name=") + "name=".length() + 1);
                    line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\""));
                    log("Adding mask = ", line);
                    fileMasks.add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new ProcessingException("Unable to open the TESTFILE.xml file",e);
    }
    return fileMasks;
}
```

And here is the applicable portion of the XML file that it is parsing:

```
<fileset>             
    <include name="filetype1*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype2*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype3*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype4*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype5*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype6*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype7*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype8*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype9*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype10*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype11*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype12*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype13*.csv"/>
    <include name="filetype14*.csv"/>
</fileset>
```

In my test environment (Windows 10) I see the following output:

```
<include name="filetype1*.csv"/>
Adding mask = filetype1*.csv
<include name="filetype2*.csv"/>
Adding mask = filetype2*.csv
<include name="filetype3*.csv"/>
...
<include name="filetype14*.csv"/>
Adding mask = filetype14*.csv
```

And in the remote server's environment I get:

```
<include name="filetype1*.csv"/>
Adding mask = 
<include name="filetype2*.csv"/>
Adding mask = 
<include name="filetype3*.csv"/>
...
<include name="filetype14*.csv"/>
Adding mask =
```

Comment: You've gone a step further than parsing XML with regex; you're writing your own XML parser. Don't. XML is a very complicated standard, and even if those features aren't being using right now someone can build simple and perfectly valid XML in the future that will knock your efforts sideways. Use an XML parser and throw all this code away.

Comment: For example `name = "filetype14*.csv"` is also valid. As are random linebreaks, comments, spaces around end tags. And about a billion other things your code ignores.

Comment: Use XMLParser Instead

Comment: Exactly what is the behavior when you run it on the server? Does it print each line (from `log(line)`) but never print "Adding mask," or does it print "Adding mask" followed by an empty string?

Comment: My guess is that you think you're testing with the same file but that the actual file on the remote server is different in some way.

Comment: I haven't used a parser because the name for the element, and the structure of the file may change dramatically over time, but those lines will always be there. This is the assumption I have been told to work with.  The behavior when run from the server prints the value from log(line) correctly but following Adding Mask is an empty string.  And the file is the same file dragged down from the remote server by WinSCP. There have been no changes made to either version.

Comment: _"but those lines will always be there"_ - `//include[@name]`

Comment: I second what @Unimportant said - if it's XML then just use XPath. Perhaps `//fileset/include[@name]` though, so you don't pick up others.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would be the case. I will try using an xpath parser and see if that changes anything, but given the simplicity of parsing a string I couldn't think of anything that would potentially cause this issue.

Comment: Have you checked that there is no whitespace after the equal sign in the remote file? ‘name= "filetype9*.csv"’ That would trigger what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be a drop-in replacement for your `parseFile` method that uses XPath to find the data you are looking for.

The XPath expression `//include[@name]` means: "give me all `<include>` in the document regardless of location that have a `name` attribute"

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

/* Other code here */

private HashSet<String> parseFile()
        throws ProcessingException
{
    String fileLocation = getInterfaceLocation();
    HashSet<String> fileMasks = new HashSet<>();

    File file = new File(fileLocation);

    try {
        // BEGIN: DOM Boilerplate
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        // END: DOM Boilerplate

        Document doc = builder.parse(file);

        XPathExpression includeQuery = xpath.compile("//include[@name]");
        NodeList includes = (NodeList) includeQuery.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < includes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element include = (Element) includes.item(i);
            fileMasks.add(include.getAttribute("name"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ProcessingException("Failed to parse file", e);
    }

    return fileMasks;
}
```

Comment: (+1) Only comment is that `include` is a fairly generic element name - you risk finding others knocking around in the document.